# can you access undo/redo history after a file is closed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code v 1.22.2

I am new to VS Code having switched over from PHPStorm for JS dev as PHPStorm was painfully slow with FlowJS.

Some people have reported a bug in VS Code where they can't undo/redo after a file is saved. While I can do that I can't seem to be able to undo/redo after a file has been *closed*. Is this a bug, setting or simply a feature not available in VS Code?

Comment: Just realised I failed to mention VS Code in the question title. Apologies. I do not know how to correct this?

Comment: In case your search arrived here and you actually want to disable this feature after a file is closed, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61527893/836330.

Answer (score 0):

I have had it confirmed on the VS Code Repo that it does not index code in that way so it is a lack of a feature. On the bright side, it is a lot faster on than PHPStorm (for FlowJS at least).

Answer (score 0):

From: [v1.46 release notes: undo in a closed file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#cross-file-undo-in-closed-files)

> #### Cross file undo in closed files
>
> It is now possible to undo across files, even if the files have been
>   closed in the meantime. The edited files will be reopened and a
>   cross-file operation, such as a rename symbol, will be undone in all
>   affected files.